# How to use Camel with Spring without XML

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm reading the Camel in Action 2nd edition, which instructs to use Spring-Camel XML-namespace configuration to embed Camel in Spring, automatically discovering Components defined as Spring beans etc. Here is an example.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>org.apache.camel.example.spring</package>
  </camelContext>

  <!-- lets configure the default ActiveMQ broker URL -->
  <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&amp;broker.useJmx=true"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

How would I achieve this without using the XML configuration but using Spring Java configuration instead?

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this documentation](http://camel.apache.org/spring-java-config.html) from camel.
And Refer [this](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/spring-java-config-example.html) for Activemq configuration.

Adding just a snippet here:

```
public class MyRouteConfiguration extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Autowire
    private MyRouteBuilder myRouteBuilder;

    @Autowire
    private MyAnotherRouteBuilder myAnotherRouteBuilder;

    @Override
    public List<RouteBuilder> routes() {
        return Arrays.asList(myRouteBuilder, myAnotherRouteBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [GitHub repository for Apache Camel](https://github.com/apache/camel) there is an [examples directory](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples).

[Take a look at the Spring Java Config example in there](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples) that is a minimal example of what you need.

Comment: The example doesn't achieve the same thing as XML-configuration. I see the whole point of camel-spring to let the camel context automatically discover beans and configure itself according to the beans present in the spring application context, i.e no registering components etc. via the camel API is required. In the example the camel context is still being configured in a manual fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java syntax and have Camel discover your beans, then you can first define your beans by returning them from a method, and use the `@Bean` and `@Configuration` annotations. For the XML sample you posted above, this would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsComponent jms() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqcf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        amqcf.setBrokerURL("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();
        jms.setConnectionFactory(amqcf);

        return jms;
    }
}
```

You can use a similar approach with your routes (use the `@Component` annotation):

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:foo?period=5000")
                .setBody(simple("Customer"))
                .to("jms:queue:customers");
    }
}
```

Then add `@ComponentScan` to your main class, which might look something like this (assuming you're using plain Spring, not Spring Boot):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends CamelConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.Main
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setConfigClass(Application.class);
        main.run();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: How would I do this when running Spring MVC inside servlet container? Where should I create the Camel context so it will be discovering Spring beans? Do I create and configure the Camel Context inside a Spring configuration class exposing it as a bean?